# how to obtain last part(dynamic id)of the url selenium webdriver

Tags: java, string, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have to take last part from url which is dynamic id generated.Can anyone help me out how to do that with java

Eg of url:
https://abc.xlri-system.com/#nnx/index.php?module=Venture&offset=2&stamp=1511358999011509300&return_module=Limited&action=CartView&record=8900000074-0b23-4fbc-afda-f03b8090dxx4

I need to extract id (Last part of url) generated after '='

Browser:Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution for your problem.

```
String url =  "https://abc.xlri-system.com/#nnx/index.php?module=Venture&offset=2&stamp=1511358999011509300&return_module=Limited&action=CartView&record=8900000074-0b23-4fbc-afda-f03b8090dxx4";
String lastPart = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("=")+1);
System.out.println(lastPart);
```

You can replace '=' with whatever identifier you are using to get extract your string.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Is there any way to achieve this with parsing query string in Java

Comment: user2392695, There are many ways to do that, long complex codes to parse a string with index computation logics.
If I was in your place, I would prefer something simpler using apache's library (using maven). Just to make your life easier.

If you prefer using apache's maven dependency, I can write a snippet for you, using that.

Comment: Actually the code is working perfectly.We are not using maven in our project...thanks for ur help:)